# NSMutableArray removeObject: throwing an error

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsmutablearray

I have an `@property (nonatomic,copy) NSMutableArray* children;`, and I'm adding/removing items to this array.

Here's the surprise:

```
- (void)addChildDocument:(PPDocument *)doc {
    [_children addObject:doc];
}

- (void)removeChildDocument:(PPDocument*)doc {

    [_children removeObject:doc];
}
```

The first one works fine. The second one doesn't.

```
-[__NSArrayI removeObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Can you please explain to me exactly what is going on and how the `children` array suddenly shows up as **immutable**?

---

**UPDATE:**

The issue has been resolved. However, as weird as it may strike you, the `copy` most of you referred to had nothing to do with the issue. Weirdly it had to do with a `parent` property of each `PPDocument` not being correctly set as `weak`. Once I did that (and leaving the `children` as it was), everything works fine - as expected. And `NSMutableArray`s remain mutable whatsoever.

Comment: @Alladinian Nope, it did not work. And, btw what you're saying doesn't seem true. If `children` is returned as an immutable object, why does `addChildDocument` work every single time?

Comment: Can you share the initialisation/assignment of the array? Also as a sidenote `copy` will always get you an immutable instance, maybe `strong` is a more suitable option.

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon Yep, I realised that you are directly accessing the ivar and deleted the first comment (unless you are using `self.children` somewhere, and reassign).

Comment: The duplicate is really about a mutable dictionary property but it's the exact same issue otherwise. FYI - not my down vote.

Comment: @rmaddy The question you've marked as dupe does not explain why one mutable method works on the array and another doesn't.  If the OP had the issue of the marked dupe question then no mutable method would work.

Comment: It doesn't "suddenly show up as immutable".  You created the immutable array when you used "copy".

Comment: Somewhere you're assigning to `self.children`.

Comment: @HotLicks that must be the case, however my answer which states that does not seem too popular :)

Comment: @Droppy - Well, it may not be that precise statement.  It could be, eg, `self.children = self.children;`, or something equivalent.

Comment: Yeah well it was kinda pseudo code that I was hoping the op would understand.  Never mind.  This site just isn't worth the effort.

Comment: @Droppy - I agree that you get a lot of folks who see asking a question here as a substitute for actual effort.

Answer (score -1):

You must be doing:

```
obj.children = @[ @"Some", @"immutable", @"array" ];
```

between those calls.

Answer (score -3):

You can't remove what you're adding in the method. You need to give him an array index.

For example,

`[_children removeObject:[_children lastObject]];`

if you know that it's always gonna be the last one.

If its not, please provide a comment with more explanation on where the object can be.

Edit : actually you might be able to do the following, could you try too?

`[_children removeObjectAtIndex:[_children indexOfObject:doc]];`

Comment: This has nothing to do with the issue.

Comment: I just tried `NSInteger ind = [_children indexOfObject:doc]; [_children removeObjectAtIndex:ind];` (which is pretty much along the lines of what you suggested, huh?) but it doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah its pretty much the same...
Was it the same error?

Because your array indeed shows up as immutable even though you're definitly working on a mutable one. Have you tried using a non copy array?

Comment: You are very much wrong.  `removeObject` expects an object to be specified.  `removeObjectAtIndex` expects an array index value.

Comment: Yeah, and i realized on top of that that i had read the error as an index problem and not a selector problem. So even if i had written my answer properly, it wasn't gonna help anyway.
I guess I shouldn't even try to answer on SO after 5pm.